# How do I install and use the Bluetile window manager in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, window-manager

I've been working on getting [bluetile](http://bluetile.org/) working on 12.04 so I can start down the path of tiling windows managers, but I have been having limited success.

I have read the (only 7!) other posts on bluetile and tried the website, but unfortunately nothing seems to address precise thoroughly enough for me to get it working.

I have tried getting gnome running on my machine via apt-get and following basic instructions from there, but without success.

The `apt-get` for bluetile also fails (on selecting the 1gnome-bluetile` session option, unity ends up opening anyway in a buggy, unstable way). I also messed around with specifying a custom xsession for lightdm to look at and setting the window-manager to bluetile, but again without success- somehow I ended up in unity again.

I can confirm that installing bluetile on a vanilla Ubuntu instance does add `Gnome + Bluetile` to the lightgdm's menu, but selecting it does nothing - it just boots into Unity.

What should I do ?

Comment: @Sergey As I understand it, software center is essentially a wrapper for apt-get: if this is true, then I did that, I think. I ran 'apt-get install bluetile', and I tried the logout-login. When I selected the new session it eventually logged in, but to unity (without the sidebar, but unity nonetheless).

I was trying gnome because some instructions I'd seen were for getting it to run in gnome. I tried [this gnome install guide](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) and then the recommendations in the posts, though I may have done something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm that installing bluetile on a vanilla Ubuntu instance does add "Gnome + Bluetile" to the lightgdm's menu, but selecting it does nothing - it just boots into Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Sergey, I appreciate the sanity check.

Comment: So it looks like a bug - I suggest you to consider reporting it. Also, while it is definitely possible to track the problem down and make bluetile work with lightdm and Unity, it may be easier just to try another, less customized flavor of Ubuntu - maybe install Xubuntu or Kubuntu in a virtual box and see if bluetile works with them without trickery.

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04. As @Sergey pointed out 5+ years ago it probably should have been filed as a bug report at the time. VTC as `not reproducible`.